# Trying to arrange objects randomly in a grid in a way that is similar to the cloner tool from Cinema4D

Tags: modifiers, transforms, geometry-nodes

I have been trying to make a looping city animation and have managed to set up all my "city block" objects in a grid with some random heights using the geometry nodes and the array modifier.[image]
[image]

Now I am trying to figure out how to Rotate all of those objects randomly in increments of 90 degrees so the repeating objects are a bit less obvious while still maintaining the grid look.

I know in C4D its cloner tool allows you to do this like so: [image]

Is there a way to do this in Blender? Ive found some tutorials already but none so far have worked or been what I was looking for.

Comment: Something like [THIS](https://imgur.com/a/D3Ixptp) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Emir proposed, you can do it like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks you two so much

Comment: You are welcome