# Geometry Nodes: Distribute on texture in a grid

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to distribute evenly spaced geometry (like in a grid) on a globe so that only the black marked area is filled.
Currently, the objects are only randomly distributed via the Geometry Nodes tree in Blender 2.93.5.
If there is only a solution with Blender 3.0 (alpha), this would not be a problem.

[image: Geometry Nodes: Globe random mask]

[image: Geometry Nodes: Node tree]

Answer (score 4):

After looking at this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234872/trying-to-arrange-objects-randomly-in-a-grid-in-a-way-that-is-similar-to-the-clo?rq=1)

here's what I found out:

[image: Result]

[image: Node tree]